# Is there any way to see your "Comment Karma"?

Tags: feature-request, comments

Is there any way to view your own "comment karma", that is, how many total upvotes I have on my comments?

I'm not looking for reputation or anything for comments, it just seems that I'd never know my comment had been upvoted unless I keep checking back on questions I have commented against.

It would also be kinda nice to see a total count of how many comments I've made, especially since a few of the badges are linked to comment counts and upvotes on comments.

Comment: You might be interested in http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/stackql/default.aspx. I used to be, but then I got my pundit badge ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run the following query if you have [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/02/querying-the-stackoverflow-data-dump/), or you can run that query on [StackQL](http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/stackql/default.aspx):

#### To see Comments sorted by Score

```
select * from comments where userid=YourUserID order by score desc
```

#### To see count of comments that are eligible for Pundit

```
select count(*) from comments where userid=YourUserID and score > 9
```

Comment: Dude I didn't even know about StackQL!  Really neat.