# How to check comment history?

Tags: discussion, comments

It always feels good if your comment has been up-voted. But, unfortunately there is no easy way to check what happened to the comment unless you go on the Q/As posted.

I tried to search meta and found [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42257/is-there-any-way-to-see-your-comment-karma) and answer too. But [link](http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/stackql/default.aspx) in the answer has been removed.

So, Is there any easy way to check comment history?

**EDIT:** By comment history I meant, how many comments did I do, and how much votes did they get.

Comment: What do you mean by "comment history?"

Comment: By comment history I meant, how many comments did I do, and how much votes did they get.

Comment: You'd have to write a data.SE query for that; I'm pretty sure it's not exposed anywhere through the front end.

Comment: That would be [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/237852/batty?tab=activity&sort=comments).  Unfortunately, you have to check each comment individually (by going to the page) to see how many votes you got.

Comment: yeah..that can be done, but I was asking for total in one place. :)

Comment: You can always look at all your comments here as well (although it wont show any votes): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/237852/batty?tab=activity&sort=comments

Comment: Sorry,I even don't understand what you asked !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an existing query in the Data Explorer that you can use to get your comments and the votes for each one.

The query is [My Most Upvoted Comments (including comment text)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/151383/my-most-upvoted-comments-including-comment-text):

```
SELECT postID [Post Link], Score, Text
FROM 
    Comments
WHERE UserId = ##UserId##
ORDER BY Score Desc
```

And you would pass into the query your user id - on Stack Overflow that would be located on your profile page URL -- https://stackoverflow.com/users/2761035/batty - it is the 2761035.

Comment: Its embarrassing for me, but I couldn't find my user-id. Where did you get that?

Comment: When in your account info, look in the search box at the top-right

Comment: @Batty see my updated answer, it is in the url of your profile page.

Comment: ooh..got that, I was searching everywhere except for these two places :P